# Passing down variable to class component with onChange for <select> tag

Tags: reactjs

How do I pass the object, tracks[currentTrack], down to the class component UserPlaylist. I haven't been able to find out any way to do this.

Playlist Component:

```
render(){
    return(
        <li><UserPlaylist onChange={(tracks)=tracks[currentTrack]}/></li>
    );
}
export default Playlist
```

UserPlaylist Component (without javascript code):

```
render() {
    return(
        <select defaultValue={"DEFAULT"}> 
            <option value="DEFAULT" disabled> Add to Playlist </option>
            {
                this.state.users_playlists.map((playlist, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={playlist.id}> { playlist.name }</option>
                ))
            }
        </select>

    );
  }
}
export default UserPlaylist;
```

Comment: Could you add more of your code to your question? It looks like you might want to pass it via `props`, and store tracks in the `state` of your Playlist component, but it is difficult to tell with only those two render functions.

Comment: You have `this.state` and `render` function, so I think you are dealing with a class component rather than a functional component. You can access the props of class components by using `this.props`. If you want to pass down the object, you don't need to use `onChange` you can put `track={tracks[currentTrack]}` and access it from `this.props.track`

Comment: are you trying to access select value from UserPlaylist component on select change in Playlist component?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to pass down? it looks like `onChange` but that indicates a function but you are saying an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can achieve if you want to do communication back and forth between components i'm assuming your using class based component

Define a function in your Playlist Component you can name anything

```
onChangeTracks=(e)=>{
      //You will get the value like this
      console.log(e.target.value)          

      //You can set your tracks here
      this.setState({
          currentTrack: tracks[currentTrack]
      })
}
```

then you need to pass this function as props to UserPlayList in PlaylistComponent like below

```
 onChangeTracks=(e)=>{
       //You will get the value like this
      console.log(e.target.value)          

      //You can set your tracks here
      this.setState({
          currentTrack: tracks[currentTrack]
      })
}

render(){
      return(
            <li><UserPlaylist tracks={this.state.currentTrack} onChange={this.onChangeTracks}/></li>
      )
}
export default Playlist
```

On other side in UserPlaylist component call this props function like below

```
render(){
   //here you will get tracks data
   console.log("Props data", this.props.tracks);

   <select onChange={this.props.onChange}> 
   </select> 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry I meant class component, I'm new to react so I confused it. But this solution works for what I needed. Although I have one small question. After the user changes the option in the select tag, I put an alert saying "track added", but how can I have the select tag return to the value=DEFAULT immediately after the alert.

Comment: Nevermind I figured out the answer to my question, Thanks again